# PrimeFaces datatable scrollbar position

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How to set a scrollbar position of primefaces datatable from last to first?

Actually, I want see the information from bottom to top. Below is my code:

```
 <p:dataTable  var="c" value="#{MessagingUserBean.inboxDetails1}" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="517" liveScroll="true" emptyMessage="No Message Found"  scrollRows="8" scrollWidth="815" >
```

Comment: No. I want to do a messaging functionality just like facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can try to not use a liveScroll because you then don't know the end of dataList. Try this and maybe this suit your needs. This will scrolldown to the bottom of your dataTable with a delay.

```
<h:form prependId="false">
          <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="c" value="#{MessagingUserBean.inboxDetails1}" scrollHeight="517" liveScroll="true" emptyMessage="No Message Found" scrollWidth="815" >

    //Your dataTable stuff
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
    <script>
        //Get the scrollheight
        var s = jQuery('#dataTable .ui-datatable-scrollable-body').prop('scrollHeight');

        //Get total size of datatable
        var o = jQuery('#dataTable .ui-datatable-scrollable-body').prop('offsetHeight');

        //calculate how many times it can scrolldown to set your timer
        var t = Math.ceil(s/o);
        //Excute scrolldown animation (max scrolldown is  scrollHeight - offsetHeight)
        $('#dataTable .ui-datatable-scrollable-body').animate({scrollTop:s-0}, t*1000);     
    </script>
```

Comment: does not change the position of the scrollbar, only the order of entries

Comment: exactly kostja. It does not change the position.

Comment: Well then i dont understand the question. Do you want to start the scrollbar on the bottom of the datatable?

Comment: @Tankhenk yes, I want start from bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You will need some javascript to do this.

```
var $scrollable = $(dataTableSelector).children('.ui-datatable-scrollable-body')[0];
$scrollable.scrollTop =  $scrollable.scrollHeight;
```

Where "dataTableSelector" is a selector for your primefaces table (a styleClass for example).

Of course, this assume that the last element in the list you're displaying is actually the first you want to show.